# golang speeding up response writing time?

Tags: performance, go, optimization, io, get-request

```
func grabPage(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, buf *[]byte) {
    defer wg.Done()
    res, err := http.Get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("./data/%d.txt", i))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = io.CopyBuffer(f, res.Body, *buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("cpuprofile")

    pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
    start := time.Now()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    total := 800

    var buf []byte
    wg.Add(total)
    for index := 0; index < total; index++ {
        go grabPage(index, &wg, &buf)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("took %s", elapsed)
}
```

I have a toy program and am simply grabbing an http request and writing it to a file. wget shows a latency of .2s and I am wondering how to get closer to this sort of speed (if possible). I have tried `io.copy`,`fasthttp`, `bufio` stream readers etc. which all were slower than the above. I just want to make sure there is nothing obvious I am missing that could speed this up as I am very new to Go. I liked fasthttp's concept of reading directly to a buffer but I think I mimicked that via io.CopyBuffer. here are my proff results :/

```
     0     0%     0%      6.78s 68.00%  io.CopyBuffer /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/io/io.go
     0     0%     0%      6.78s 68.00%  io.copyBuffer /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/io/io.go
     0     0%     0%      5.44s 54.56%  net/http.(*http2gzipReader).Read /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go
     0     0%     0%      5.41s 54.26%  compress/gzip.(*Reader).Read /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/compress/gzip/gunzip.go
     0     0%     0%      5.35s 53.66%  compress/flate.(*decompressor).Read /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/compress/flate/inflate.go
 0.92s  9.23%  9.23%      5.20s 52.16%  compress/flate.(*decompressor).huffmanBlock /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/compress/flate/inflate.go
 2.97s 29.79% 39.02%      2.99s 29.99%  syscall.Syscall /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s
 0.01s   0.1% 39.12%      2.59s 25.98%  internal/poll.(*FD).Write /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go
 1.02s 10.23% 49.35%      2.53s 25.38%  compress/flate.(*decompressor).huffSym /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/compress/flate/inflate.go
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that you don't close the `res.Body` after reading from it. This might prevent connection reuse IIRC.

Comment: Data race condition alert. You share buf []byte across 800 goroutines which  lead to concurent r/w. Slices and maps are not safe for concurent r/w. &buf is also useless because slice is always passed by pointer.

Comment: Trying to download the same page with 800 concurrent connections is rarely going to be faster. Limit your connections and reuse them.

Comment: @JimB could you show an example of what you mean? Does this mean creating a new client every n times rather than w/ each function call?

Comment: @Maximus12793: No, I mean don't open 800 _concurrent_ connections. Use a small worker pool, or a semaphore, or don't fetch the same thing 800 times. You have to test what the optimal concurrency is for your upstream connection and latency, probably somewhere between 1 and 20. If you're only trying to contact a single host, make sure the http transport is going to maintain enough connections for your desired concurrency.

Comment: http.Client maintains a connection pool automatically (with the default transport anyway), so no, do not create multiple clients. However, you have to close the response body when you're done with it, otherwise the connection cannot be reused. And as bigless mentioned, don't share the buffer. io.Copy is pretty smart and usually does the Right Thing.

Comment: Ok great so really I am just running up against the syscall copy limit right? Just want to make sure there are no other tricks I can do like pre-allocate space for the biggest file size or disable gc etc.