# Why do my Futures not max out the CPU?

Tags: multithreading, rust, multiprocessing, threadpool, fibers

I am creating a few hundred requests to download the same file (*this is a toy example*). When I run the equivalent logic with Go, I get 200% CPU usage and return in ~5 seconds w/ 800 reqs. In Rust with only 100 reqs, it takes nearly 5 seconds and spawns 16 OS threads with 37% CPU utilization.

Why is there such a difference?

From what I understand, if I have a `CpuPool` managing `Future`s across **N** cores, this is functionally what the Go runtime/goroutine combo is doing, just via fibers instead of futures.

From the perf data, it seems like I am only using 1 core despite the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
extern crate curl;
extern crate fibers;
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_cpupool;

use std::io::{Write, BufWriter};
use curl::easy::Easy;
use futures::future::*;
use std::fs::File;
use futures_cpupool::CpuPool;


fn make_file(x: i32, data: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    let f = File::create(format!("./data/{}.txt", x)).expect("Unable to open file");
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&f);
    writer.write_all(data.as_mut_slice()).unwrap();
}

fn collect_request(x: i32, url: &str) -> Result<i32, ()> {
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url(url).unwrap();
    {
        let mut transfer = easy.transfer();
        transfer
            .write_function(|d| {
                data.extend_from_slice(d);
                Ok(d.len())
            })
            .unwrap();
        transfer.perform().unwrap();

    }
    make_file(x, &mut data);
    Ok(x)
}

fn main() {
    let url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant";
    let pool = CpuPool::new(16);
    let output_futures: Vec<_> = (0..100)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|ind| {
            pool.spawn_fn(move || {
                let output = collect_request(ind, url);
                output
            })
        })
        .collect();

    // println!("{:?}", output_futures.Item());
    for i in output_futures {
        i.wait().unwrap();
    }
}
```

[My equivalent Go code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510272/golang-speeding-up-response-writing-time?noredirect=1#comment80006414_46510272)

Comment: Are you compiling and running your program with the **--release** flag?

Comment: @Shepmaster yes with optimization level 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand, if I have a `CpuPool` managing `Future`s across **N** cores, this is functionally what the Go runtime/goroutine combo is doing, just via fibers instead of futures.

This is not correct. The [documentation for `CpuPool` states](https://docs.rs/futures-cpupool/0.1.6/futures_cpupool/struct.CpuPool.html), emphasis mine:

> A thread pool intended to run **CPU intensive work**.

Downloading a file is *not* CPU-bound, it's IO-bound. All you have done is spin up many threads then told each thread to block while waiting for IO to complete.

Instead, use [tokio-curl](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-curl), which adapts the curl library to the `Future` abstraction. You can then remove the threadpool completely. This should drastically improve your throughput.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't most of the overhead waiting for the network so if I have spawned a future for each request shouldn't it **not** block until the response is available and I can write to file? Is tokio generally well suited for other io bound tasks like writing to many files etc?

Comment: @Maximus12793 *Isn't most of the overhead waiting for the network*  — yes, which is why I said "Downloading a file is [...] IO-bound". *shouldn't it not block* — yes, except that you have performed a blocking call (`.perform()`). *Is tokio generally well suited for other io bound* — yes, I'm pretty sure that's why it's called Tok**io**, and AFAIK is the entire reason Tokio exists. *like writing to many files* — sadly, there's [basically no good async disk IO](http://blog.libtorrent.org/2012/10/asynchronous-disk-io/).